# How To Destruct Destructor-less Types Constructed via 'Placement New'

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

So I have built class with which I intended to use `std::aligned_storage` to store different types up to 16 bytes in for a 'Variant' class. Theoretically it should be able to store any POD type and common containers such as `std::string` and `std::map`.

I went by the code example found here, and it seemed like it was made for exactly what I was looking for: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage

My version, basically:

```
class Variant {
public:
    Variant() { /* construct */ }
    Variant(std::map<int,int> v) {
        new(&m_data) std::map<int,int>(v);  // construct std::map<int,int> at &m_data
        m_type = TYPE_MAP;
    }
    ~Variant() {
        if (m_type == TYPE_MAP) {
            // cool, now destruct..?
            reinterpret_cast<std::map<int, int>*>(&m_data)->~/*???????????????*/();
        }
    }

private:
    // type of object in m_data
    enum Type m_type;
    // chunk of space for allocating to
    std::aligned_storage<16, std::alignment_of<std::max_align_t>::value>::type m_data;
};
```

My problem comes with the destruction. As you can see at `/*???????????????*/`, I'm not sure what to call in place of `~T()` in the cppreference.com example:

```
reinterpret_cast<const T*>(data+pos)->~T();  // I did the same thing except I know what T is, is that a problem is it?
```

In my mind, I'm doing exactly the same thing, disregarding template anonymity. Problem is, `std::map` doesn't have any `std::map::~map()` destructor method, only a `std::map::~_Tree`, which is clearly not intended for direct use. So, in the cppreference.com example code, what would `~T()` be calling if `T` was an `std::map<int,int>`, and what is the proper way for me to call the destructor for an object with a known type in `std::aligned_storage`? Or am I over complicating things and are the `clear()` methods in these STL containers guaranteed do the equivalent of full destruction's?

Or, is there any simpler way around this? As I've possibly misunderstood something along the way regarding my intended usage of `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: What makes you think there is no `std::map::~map()`? There certainly is.

Comment: Ah, I was going to ask as well whether it was anything to do with my compiler specifically but must have edited it out. So, am I looking at an issue with Visual Studio 2015's support of C++11 or something here? Because there's almost definitely none in the header file... @Brian

Comment: All classes have a destructor (compiler implicitly declares if you don't), and  you can also use `~T()` syntax on non-class types for which it is defined as a no-op

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have read the header file where `std::map` is defined and think that `std::map` has no destructor because you could not find the declaration of a destructor.

However, in C++, a type that doesn't have a destructor declared will have a destructor *implicitly* declared by the compiler. This implicit destructor will call the destructors of bases and non-static members. It sounds like the `std::map` in your library implementation is a thin layer over `_Tree`. Therefore, all that needs to be done to destroy the map is to destroy the tree. Therefore, the compiler's default destructor does the trick.

It is allowed to write `->~map()` in your case, and it will call the implicitly defined destructor, and the map will be destroyed correctly. You may also use this syntax with scalar types such as `int` (but not arrays, for some reason).

Comment: Ah, so I'm just being prematurely put off by its lack of presence in Visual Studio's Intellisense suggestions and the header file itself. I guess I was just thinking there was something specifically wrong with _explicit_ destruction of certain objects. D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure what to call in place of `~T()`

Your type, which is named `map`:

```
reinterpret_cast<std::map<int, int>*>(&m_data)->~map();
```

Which if it makes you feel better you can put in a function template:

```
template <class T>
void destroy_as(void* p) {
    static_cast<T*>(p)->~T();
}

destroy_as<std::map<int, int>>(&m_data);
```

> Problem is, `std::map` doesn't have any `std::map::~map()` destructor method

It may be compiler generated, but the type assuredly *has* a destructor. All types have destructors. Some may be explicitly or impleted `delete`d, but they exist.

---

Note that your `aligned_storage` is too small to store a `map`, `sizeof(std::map)` is larger than 16.

Comment: It appears to be 12 in Visual Studios implementation, I'm not so surprised it's not the same across the board. I adapted my example from my source which was using `std::string` (as it had `std::string::~basic_string()`, making the situation less of an apparent conundrum). I was planning on adding `std:map` support too though, so that reminds me I need to check into that deeper before continuing, thanks.